# Getting value using indirection operator

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

If value are stored in an address, then what does this declaration do

```
int a = 10;
```

It store the value in a or in address of &a. And if it store the value in address of a, then why we can't using indirection to this variable like this:

```
printf("%d", *a);
```

If not, then how we can say that the each value has an unique address and we can access them using indirection operator.

**Edit:** If I think that indirection is used only on pointer, then consider this:

```
int b[10];
b[0] = 4;  // Give it some value
```

Now we know that b[0] is a scalar quantity and can be used anywhere where scalar value are required. But in this case, we can use indirection to it like this:

```
printf("%d", *b);  // print 4
```

Isn't interesting to see that we can use pointer on this scalar variable, but cannot use on variable declare without array.

In my opinion, compiler automatically generates an indirection for variable declare like this:

```
int a = 4;
```

So, indirection is not possible on this because we are putting another indirection on it which is not legal except in cases when variables are declares like that:

```
int a = 4; 
int *b = &a; 
int **c = &b;
```

**Edit 2:** You can take `scanf("%d", &a)` as a proof which says store the value in address of a not in a.

Comment: The operand of the indirection operator must be a pointer to a type.

Comment: array names are special in the way that they act like pointers

Comment: *It store the value in a or in address of &a* not necessarily. `a` may be stored in a register, or it may be optimized away entirely in some cases. `a` is not a address, it's an `int` variable which the compiler *might* implement using a memory location.

Comment: @Caleb: Yes, I know `a` is not an address, but what I've said in question that it stores the value in address of a (i.e. &a). You can take `scanf("%d", &a)` as a proof for this.

Comment: Your question seems to be (it's a little hard to tell) why you can't say: `int a = 10; printf("%d", *a);`. The reason is that `a` is an `int`, not an `int *`, that is, it's the value stored at the address &a, not the address itself. You say that you know `a` is not an address, but if you know that, then it should be clear that you can't dereference it using `*a`.

Comment: @Caleb `a` already has a 1st level of indirection (which I called self-pointer) performed by compiler. So, if I write `printf("%d", *a);` then it has two indirection performed on it which is not possible except in cases if you do like this: `int *b = &a; int **c = &b; printf("%d", **c);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the variable is of type `int` (rather than `int *`), the compiler knows that it needs to do the indirection for you, and you shouldn't try to make it do it.  That is, when you have `int a = 10;`, the compiler stores the value at a memory location which is represented by `&a` (ignoring registers) and it knows that when you write `printf("%d\n", a);` it is required to fetch the value stored at `&a` automatically without you having to think about telling it to dereference something.

When the variable is of type `int *` (e.g. `int *p`), there are two ways you can read the value:

- Fetch the value (an address) that is held in `p`
- Fetch the value held at the address stored in `p`

These are two different operations, so two notations are needed:

```
int  a = 10;
int *p = &a;
int *q = p;
int  r = *p;
```

Of course, `p` also has its own address.

Comment: in what scenario does the compiler do indirection for you?

Comment: In the context where you write `a = 10;` or `int s = a;` — it knows that `a` is stored at an address that would be `&a` (unless the value is in a register, but let's not complicate things).  But there's no need to tell the compiler 'when I write `a`, I want you to fetch the value that is stored in the address where `a` is stored'.

Comment: So, I am right the compiler automatically generates a 1st level of indirection for all scalar values whether it is array or simple variable and this is how the pointer works.

Comment: maybe my C lingo needs a brush up, but I don't think of that as indirection... though I agree that there is an abstract indirection going on, in that the variable has an address...

Comment: @GradyPlayer: I would agree ; I don't think of `int s = a;` as an indirection, but the question is written in such a way that it seemed that the OP was trying to think in such terms, so I tried to address their question in their terms.

Answer (score 3):

Up to a certain point you are right: `a` stores an `int` and lives at the address `&a`.

But indirection can only be used on pointers. So you could do either of

```
int a = 10;
int *p = &a;
printf("%d", a);
printf("%d", *(&a));
printf("%d", *p);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what the question is here, so I'll just explain the situation...

Each (global) variable is located somewhere in memory. When it is assigned a value, that value will in memory at the location of the variable.

If you, in C, use the variable, you actually use the value stored at the location of the variable.

One way to see this is that if `&` takes the address of an object, and `*` dereferences (follows) a pointer, then `* &a` is the same as simply `a`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
int a = 10;
```

The compiler allocates memory of enough size to accomodate an `int`. This location has to be *identified*(this is at this particular place i.e. the address) and *labelled*(this location is called `a`).It then stores the data at that point. The label allows you easier access. If the language was designed in a way that you would only have access to locations via pointers (i.e  dereferencing them to get values) it will be difficult.

You can say its like, You live on some piece of land which can be pinpointed by an exact latitude and longitude. But its better to keep a name for that location, MyHouse etc. rather than referring to the latitude/longitude everytime. Both name and longi/lati refer to the same thing.

`a` is the label. `&a` is more like longi/lati

**Edit:** Regarding `int b[10]`. array names are not plain labels. They also act as pointers  and hence you can use `*` to dereference them

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot use the indirection operator on anything that does not have a pointer type.

Remember that declarations in C are based on the types of *expressions*, not objects; the declaration

```
int a = 10;
```

says that the *expression* `a` has type `int`, and will evaluate to the value of `10` (at least until someone assigns a different value to it).  So when you write

```
printf("%d\n", a);
```

the compiler knows to retrieve the value stored at the memory location bound to the expression `a`.  Think of this as a *direct access*.

Now consider the declaration

```
int *p = &a;
```

This declaration says that the *expression* `*p` has type `int`, and will evaluate to the value of whatever `p` is currently pointing to (in this case, `*p` will evaluate to `10` since `p` is initialized with the address of `a`); the indirection operator is part of the declaration (and is bound to the declarator `*p`, not the type specifier `int`).  The variable `p` is a *pointer* to an integer, and it stores the *address* of another integer variable (in this case, the address of the variable `a`).  Thus, if we want to access the integer value, we must *dereference* `p`:

```
printf("%d\n", *p);
```

This is an *indirect* access to the value `10`; instead of accessing it through the variable `a`, we're accessing it through `p` *which points to* `a`.